# random BigInteger array within a given range

Tags: java, arrays, random, biginteger

How can I generate an array of random BigIntegers in the range from 1024 to 2048 bits in Java? The solution should be found without importing any additional external library.

Comment: What is the language? What is "external class"?

Comment: in Java, any external libraries should not be imported
@AlmaDo

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses only built-in standard libraries:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

// ...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    // This constructor generates a BigInteger of the number of bits given in the first argument,
    // using a random value taken from the generator passed as the second argument.
    BigInteger randomInteger = new BigInteger(1024, randomGenerator);
}
```

If you want a random number that is hard to predict, you can instead select a secure random generator:

```
Random randomGenerator = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
```

(catch or declare the `NoSuchAlgorithmException`)